# Mathematica refuses to integrate a function it knows how to integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Let $a$, $b$, and $k$ be positive real numbers, and consider the integral
$$ \iiint\limits_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3} \delta(a \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert^k -b) \ \mathrm{d}^3\mathbf{x} = \frac{4\pi}{bk} \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{3/k} $$
where $\delta$ denotes the Dirac delta function. If we try asking *Mathematica 10.1* to evaluate this for us,

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[a (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(k/2) - b],
    {x, y, z} ~Element~ FullRegion[3],
    Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, k > 0}]
```

it just spits the integral back out without solving anything. "Okay," you say, "*Mathematica* must not be clever enough with Dirac delta functions to work this one out." But wait! Suppose we put in some concrete but absolutely unrelated values for $a$, $b$, and $k$. For example,

```
a = BesselJ[1, Pi];
b = BesselJ[2, Pi];
k = BesselJ[3, Pi];
```

Now, if we try evaluating the above integral again, the desired result is obtained!

$$ \frac{4\pi}{J_2(\pi) J_3(\pi)} \left( \frac{J_2(\pi)}{J_1(\pi)} \right)^{3/J_3(\pi)} =\frac{4\pi}{bk} \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)^{3/k} $$

This tells me that *Mathematica* must know how to do the integral, since whatever *Mathematica* did for these particular values ought to work equally well for general values of $a$, $b$, and $k$. So why does it refuse to do the integral without the particular values in place?

Comment: The original integral, as well as the equivalent `Integrate[DiracDelta[a (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(k/2) - b], {x, -∞, ∞}, {y, -∞, ∞}, {z, -∞, ∞},  Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, k > 0}]` work in 10.3, tho. Try the alternative and report back.

Comment: @J.M. Your alternative doesn't work either for me using 10.1. I'll have to install 10.3 tomorrow morning.'

Comment: Both the OP's original expression and J. M.♦'s alternative work for me on 10.0.2.0.

Comment: @J.M. Huh, closing and re-opening *Mathematica* seems to have fixed the problem! Guess I was too hasty in asking this question. You may close it.